# Cannot parse datetime in pm format with booster, C++, graphlab

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, graphlab, sframe

I've tried to convert datetime string into datetime of an SArray (uses C++ booster library), but it does not seem to understand the `%p` format specifier. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html
This documentation says specifiers marked with `!` `do not currently work for input`. 
Does that mean that you cannot parse anything with `pm` or `PM`?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the string-to-datetime conversion to work by making two small changes:

1. Use %I for the hour on a 12-hour clock (%H is for a 24 hour clock).
2. Use %P (upper case) for the AM/PM flag.

Here's what works for me:

```
sf = gl.SFrame({'date': ['2015-11-06 02:12:42 pm', 
                         '2015-11-05 03:43:11 pm']})
sf['date2'] = sf['date'].str_to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
```